# How do I verify an openshift domain with mailgun?

Tags: dns, openshift, mailgun

I'm trying to send mail from my gear using Mailgun. The [Mailgun instructions](https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#verify-your-domain) for verification require adding new records but I can't see any configurable DNS settings accessible via the OpenShift console.

One solution would be to configure a custom domain alias and then use my domain management DNS console, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you already know how to use an OpenShift alias for your domain. You can use CloudFlare and add a CNAME for your gear. See below example for additional things you need to put on CloudFlare for a working mailgun configuration.

(Simply replace yourdomain.com with your own domain name)

```
;; MX Records
yourdomain.com.      300     IN      MX      10      mxa.mailgun.org.
yourdomain.com.      300     IN      MX      10      mxb.mailgun.org.

;; TXT Records
mx._domainkey.yourdomain.com.        300     IN      TXT     "k=rsa\; p=M............QAB"
mg.yourdomain.com.   300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
yourdomain.com.      300     IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"

;; CNAME Records
www.yourdomain.com.  300     IN      CNAME   www-yourdomain.rhcloud.com.
email.mg.yourdomain.com.     300     IN      CNAME   mailgun.org.
email.yourdomain.com.        300     IN      CNAME   mailgun.org.
```

Comment: So there's no way to do it without having your own domain elsewhere?

Comment: You need a dns service to be able to do that. Please accept the answer.